# how to format the mac book?

Tags: mac

I want to format my mac book is there any documentation about the formatting of the mac book?

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thank you
Monish.

Answer (score 2):

Start from the System Install disk (hold down the option key at startup). Select your language, select Utilities from the menu bar, select Disk Utility, Erase. This will completely reformat your drive, erasing all of your data... Why do you want to do this? Is there some problem that you are trying to fix?

Comment: IS only O.S intallation is enough or need to install any other software after this.

Comment: O.S. installation should be enough, but i think there will be some software you would want to install in addition.

Comment: If this is because you want to sell the MacBook, give Secure Erase a consideration. It will take a lot of time, but makes (reasonably) sure that no data can be recovered. There is even an option to do this more than once (then it really takes a long time), but that should not be necessary unless you (or the buyer) work for the NSA or something.